# Vaadin 7 : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available

Tags: java, vaadin7

Why i'm getting this error :

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. See previous log messages for more information.
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:240)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

When i'm using the Push annotation :

```
@Push(PushMode.MANUAL)
public class KopivaadincomponentsUI extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {...

   }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Vaadin 7.1? Issue similar in: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3339684.  "Unfortunately Vaadin 7.1 will not support push with portlets" unless a patches fixed it currently.

Comment: So does that answer you?

Comment: Sorry but it works in another 7.1 vaadin project this is why i'm still looking for a solution

Answer (score 4):

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            <version>${com.vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Try adding this Dependency to your .pom file.